# I am trying to write a xamarin forms application to simply take a photo and save the image,

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, camera

The error i am getting is as follows

System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to get file location. This most likely means that the file provider information is not set in your Android Manifest file.

I have gone through all the suggestions i can find regarding permissions for fileprovider to no avail
The code where it is failing is..

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
{
    Directory = "",
    SaveToAlbum = true
});
```

(I have tried setting "Directory" to "images", "pictures" and just about anything else you can think of !

resources/file_paths.xml is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" /> 
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

My AndroidManifest .xml is ...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:icon="@drawable/Woodstonelogo"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:label="App1.Android">
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you trying to save picture to a smart card on Android?  The error either means you did not mount the smart card when the Android was started or the smart card is locked and you have to first unlock the smart card before using.  What I normally recommend with smart card is to first make sure using an file explorer that your can read and write the card before trying to use with a c# app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause :**
In your **AndroidManifest.xml** you define two **application** tags . So the first one will work in default . So the provider will never been set  as it's in the second tag .

**Solution:**

Modify the code like following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app1" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="App1.Android" android:icon="@drawable/Woodstonelogo"> 
      <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
      </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: That just works a treat... But why on earth could i not see that ???? i had read about AND checked for multiple application tags

Comment: i cant see a tick anywhere to mark as an answer, but thatnks for the help, much appreciated by a solo developer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work